# LND how to recover abandoned channel

Tags: lightning-network-daemon, channels, ln-closing-channels

Years ago I used LND's abandonchannel command to abandon two channels, it was stupid and I didn't know what I was doing at the time.
These are the only sats I ever lost.

Ever since, whenever I use the updatechanpolicy command to change the fees on my channels I get an error stating that for those specific two channels the fees can't be changed because the channels can't be found.

```
{
        "failed_updates": [
                {
                        "outpoint": "[redacted]:1",
                        "reason": "UPDATE_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER",
                        "update_error": "channel not found"
                },
                {
                        "outpoint": "[redacted]:0",
                        "reason": "UPDATE_FAILURE_INVALID_PARAMETER",
                        "update_error": "channel not found"
                }
        ]
}
```

So somehow the channels have not been entirely removed from LND's DB.
When I look up the channel points in a block explorer I find that both UTXO's still exist so my channel partners have not been able to close the channels either. I have tried contacting the channel partners so maybe they could broadcast a close tx but had no succes there.

Is there any way to construct a closing tx and finally close these channels to onchain?
If not, how do I permanently remove them from the DB?